# public поля/методы в package-access классе.

Tags: java

Какой смысл у такой конструкции:

```
package foo;
class Bar {
    public int i;
}
```

Ведь вне пакета foo все равно нельзя получить доступ к i?

Comment: Но внутри foo -- можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Получить доступ напрямую нельзя, но какой-нибудь класс с `public`-доступом может вернуть нам экземпляр `package-access` класса в виде интерфейса.

Берем `public` интерфейс

```
package foo;
public interface Foo {
    public void doFoo();
}
```

и реализуем его в `package-access` классе

```
package foo;
class FooImpl implements Foo {
    public void doFoo() {
        //some stuff
    }
}
```

Теперь `public` класс из того же пакета `foo` сможет вернуть `FooImpl` в виде `Foo`.

```
package foo;
public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo getSomeFoo() {
        return new FooImpl();
    }
}
```

Готово. Теперь мы можем использовать `foo.Foo` из в каком-нибудь другом пакете и не подозревать, что это на самом деле `FooImpl`:

```
package bar;
import foo.Foo;
import foo.FooFactory;
public class Bar {
    public void bar() {
        Foo foo = FooFactory.getSomeFoo();
        foo.doFoo();
    }
}
```

Таким образом, мы скрыли реализацию интерфейса `Foo`.

Comment: Вот она, ООП. "И эти люди запрещают мне ковырять в носу!" Хотя до вершин Master Programmer в (одна из ссылок) http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html ещё далеко.

Comment: интересная штука, но я бы предпочел избегать такие ситуации

Comment: Ну почему же. Вполне адекватная ситуация. Например, внутри пакета у вас что-то вроде конечного автомата, парсера или просто дерева объектов (паттерн State в общем) и вы не хотите раскрывать пользователю библиотеки детали реализации.

Comment: банальный пример где такое оправдано это одно/двунаправленые реализации интерфейса list. кроме самих элементов вам нужно еще хранить 1 или 2 ссылки, поэтому каждый элемент списка сначала заворачивается в класс Entry с полями:

    class Entry<E> {
    private E item;
    private Entry<E> next;
    private Entry<E> prev;
    ...
    }

конечному пользователю совсем не обязательно знать о существовании этого класса ведь он оперирует с методами класса list: `void add(E item); void remove(E item);` etc...